# Current row index of a column

Tags: python, pandas

```
df[A] = calculate_fee(df[B], df[C], df[D], System_Ch, df[CE][df.index].values)
```

I am creating a new column `A` by calling a function `calculate_fee` last argument in function is expected to be a value not the whole series.
So, I need to pick value from Col `E` from the current index of run when creating column `A`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

To get value at an index, you can use .iloc as follows:

```
>> import pandas as pd
>> mydict = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4},{'a': 100, 'b': 200, 'c': 300, 'd': 400},{'a': 1000, 'b': 2000 , 'c': 3000, 'd': 4000 }]
>> index = 0  # this should come during the iteration
>> df_1 = pd.DataFrame(mydict)
>> df_1['c'].iloc[index]  # also df_1['c'][index]
>> 3
>> # In your example
>> df_1['A'] = calculate_fee(df_1['a'], df_1['b'], df_1['c'], System_Ch, df_1['d'].iloc[index])
```

Comment: I tried this, I am getting following error- "NameError: name 'index' is not defined"

Comment: index should be the iteration value. Does your code fit into a loop? Can you update the question with more lines of code?

Comment: df_1['A'] = calculate_fee(df_1['a'], df_1['b'], df_1['c'], System_Ch, df_1['d'].iloc[index])

Comment: "NameError: name 'index' is not defined" is specific to your code. As you said in your question it should be any variable pointing to the `current index of run `.
Can you paste in the whole loop?